# Checking different row while in a statement

Tags: mysql

i am trying to check if the player_id is in anywhere in "user_lineup" paired by team_id

`SELECT player_id FROM user_players WHERE team_id = 134 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_lineup)`

`SELECT player_id FROM user_players WHERE team_id = 134 AND player_id NOT IN user_lineup`

`SELECT player_id FROM user_players WHERE team_id = 134 NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_lineup WHERE team_id = 1)`

i know i am missing something, but not sure what to do i have tried the above methods and it returns 0 rows, i am trying to see if `player_id` is in  `user_lineup` where `team_id` are the same.

i have read about `JOIN` but is this needed if i am just checking if a row has a value the same as `player_id`.

```
user_players
id | player_id | player_name | team_id
1  | 343       |  example    |    1

user_lineup - (pos1 & pos2 are player_id)
id    | pos2   | pos1     | team_id
234   | 36367  | 234347   | 1
```

i need to see if `player_id` is is anywhere in `user_lineup` where the `team_id`  is the same.

Please change the title of this question to something more relevant as i am not sure what i am asking.

thank you in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to have a copy of your schema to refer to.

Comment: sorry yes didnt think.

Comment: @Nashie  are the columns  pos1 and pos2 where the userid is stored or the id field?

Comment: pos1 and pos2 are ```player_id``` these are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user_id is related to pos1 or pos2 you can use following query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user_players (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `player_id` INTEGER,
>   `player_name` VARCHAR(7),
>   `team_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO user_players
>   (`id`, `player_id`, `player_name`, `team_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '343', 'example', '1');
>
> CREATE TABLE user_lineup (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `pos2` INTEGER,
>   `pos1` INTEGER,
>   `team_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO user_lineup
>   (`id`, `pos2`, `pos1`, `team_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('234', '36367', '234347', '1'),
>   ('235', '343', '234348', '1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     up.*, ul.pos1, ul.pos2
> FROM
>     user_players up
>         INNER JOIN
>     user_lineup ul ON ul.`team_id` = up.`team_id`
>         AND ( up.`player_id` = ul.`pos1` OR  up.`player_id` = ul.`pos2`)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | player_id | player_name | team_id |   pos1 | pos2
> -: | --------: | :---------- | ------: | -----: | ---:
>  1 |       343 | example     |       1 | 234348 |  343
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58ac66e017b840e98c0fcb3ce8079954)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i needed to check if its not in the row, i changed ```AND``` to ```AND NOT ``` now you have explained it i can see it clearly thanks again.